# Overriding routes in the Clearance gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, clearance

I'm using the clearance gem to add authentication to a rails app. I would like to use a different layout called 'session' with the sessions and passwords controllers. In order to do this I'll need to override the sessions and passwords controllers, but so far I can't get either of them to use my alternative layout.

I've added a sessions controller that inherits from clearance and my layout file is in the correct place.

```rb
class SessionsController < Clearance::SessionsController
  layout 'session'
end
```

I've done the same as above with the passwords controller. Now I add a route that I hoped would override the one that the clearance gem uses:

```rb
resource :session, controller: 'sessions'
```

But this has no effect and the application layout is used. How can I use a different layout with these controllers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overriding the layouts is simpler than this: See: https://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance#overriding-layouts

```
Clearance::PasswordsController.layout 'my_passwords_layout'
Clearance::SessionsController.layout 'my_sessions_layout'
Clearance::UsersController.layout 'my_admin_layout'
```